# DOM.getBoundingClientRect doesn't fire on window scroll event but on resize [Vuejs]

Tags: javascript, events, vue.js, scroll

**CASE:**
i'm making an infinite scroll on a website, a table that has to load more rows when the bottom of the table reaches the botom of the viewport from outside of it)

**Code**
To do so, first of all i setted a windowHeight variable in data, and in created lifehook i first setted it to the window.innerheight and added a resize eventlistener on the window object to set the windowHeight variable to the cuirrent window.innerheight, like this:

```
data() {
  return {
    windowHeight: 0,
  }
}

created() {
  this.windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
  window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    this.windowHeight = window.innerHeight
  })
}
```

then i setted a variable called topRect and setted it to the topRect of a div i placed right after the table on the template, so when the topRect of that element is lower than the window innerheight, it has to fire a method to load more data, i have done this like this:

**script**

```
data() {
  return {
    windowHeight: 0,
    topRect: 0,
    divAfterTable: '',
  }
}

created() {
  this.windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
  window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    this.windowHeight = window.innerHeight
  })
}

mounted() {
  this.divAfterTable = document.querySelector(#div-after-table)
  this.topRect = this.divAfterTable.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  window.addEventListener('scroll', this.setClientRect)
  })
}

methods: {
  setClientRects() {
    this.topRect = this.divAfterTable.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  }
}
```

**template**

```
<template>
  <div class="table">
    <div class="table__container">
      <table class="table__fixture">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>col 1</td>
            <td>col 2</td>
            <td>col 3</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-if="tableData.data" v-for="row in tableData" :key="row.id">
            <td>{{row.colOne}}</td>
            <td>{{row.colTwo}}</td>
            <td>{{row.colThree}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="div-after-table"></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

the rest of the code for the feature is irrelevant.

**Expected Behavior:**

the setClientRect method should fire on scroll and update the topRect variable, but it doesn't, it just fires when the window is resized, the strange part is that i putted a console.log('it works') INSIDE the setClientRects method like this:

```
methods: {
  setClientRects() {
    this.topRect = this.divAfterTable.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  }
}
```

and it is logged, but the rest of the method just doesn't work unless i resize the window

**Weird Behavior and probably useful data:**

i have a mid complex structure of components on the project, and i have to apply this on two different components, the weird thing is that i works perfectly on one component, but it doesn't on the other one, the case is that the component where it doesn't work is being rendered inside a router-view that is already inside another router-view (it's a child route), the component have this structure:

```
<Root>
  <App>
    <Navbar>
    <News> router-view: /news <-- HERE IT WORKS

<Root>
  <App>
    <Navbar>
    <League> router-view: /league 
      <Statistics> router-view /league/statistics <-- HERE IT DOESN'T
```

if you need more info, let me know

Answer (score 0):

Not all sure, but I see you're using document.querySelector here, is there a reason why you're not using:

```
this.$el.querySelector
```

You could also make use of [Vue Refs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) of course, but maybe I have misunderstood your problem.

Comment: i didn't know that part of the API of Vuejs to be honest, but i tried it and it doesn't help to fix the problem, due to the fact that is just another way to target an element. Anyway, it is valuable information to apply on future developments.